# What are the dangers of sourcing ~/.profile from ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash, bashrc, .profile

I see many people do the opposite. Are there any reasons why it is a bad idea to source `~/.profile` from `~/.bashrc`?

```
# .bashrc

if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
    source ~/.profile
fi
```

I've done a lot of searching and usually people do the following:

```
# .bash_profile

if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
    source ~/.profile
fi

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

I need some env variables in `~/.profile` to be defined for an interactive shell that is not a login shell (thus I'm using `~/.bashrc`). Is this opening me to any dangers?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/703584/334516

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing your `.bashrc` and your `.profile`, we can't say. For example, the default `.profile` on Ubuntu sources `.bashrc`. Now if you source `.profile` from `.bashrc`, you get an infinite loop:

```
$ bash  
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  bash
```

(I use zsh, that's why zsh reports the segfault.)

You could place guards that ensure these files get sourced at most once, but who knows what else may interact weirdly?

For your environment variables problem, it depends on how you're starting this interactive non-login shell. Try `.pam_environment` instead.

Comment: I see. Why Ubuntu sources .bashrc from .profile? Profile, AFAIK, should be used only for setting env (works with bash and sh). My profile only changes PATH in my example.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/432508/158442

Comment: It doesnt. Or shouldnt.